# How can I make the button appear after the paragraph in responsive mode?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working on a page with an introduction text and a button on the right. It looks ok on desktop, however I'd like to move the button below the intro text in responsive mode. How can I go about doing that? Here's what I came up with. I've also provided a link to jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/tpeob5a6/1/

Thanks for your time.

```css
.container {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="1">
<img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt="Smiley face" style="float:right;">
Intro text:

I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertrytI'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertrytI'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertrytI'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertrytI'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a media query and set the button to appear after the text using the `order` property.

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/auf7pgrm/1/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {

  .container > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  img {
    order: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="1">
    <img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt="Smiley face" style="float:right;">
    Intro text:

    I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertrytI'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertrytI'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertrytI'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertrytI'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, avoid using numbers to start a class value. You may find that browsers ignore it. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31773673/3597276

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the `@media` selector to specify the breaking point for when you want to go from `flex-direction: row` to `column`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

img {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .div1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  img {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">
    <img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt="Smiley face">
    <p>
      Intro text: I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg
      fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!!
      tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertrytI'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!!
      I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertrytI'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!!
      I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertrytI'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!!
      I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertrytI'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt I'm riiiight!!!
      I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! I'm riiiight!!! tedsffdg g fg gh g h hg fhg h gh gh gf h g hgh eertryt
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: changed media width to make it easier to demo

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but the problem is the text doesn't wrap below the button  in desktop. I see you removed no wrap. I want the text to still wrap in desktop below the button.

Comment: @newuser updated! Text-wrap works on desktop now